# Pyinstaller Scipy.stats norm import does not work

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

The Scipy.stats fucntion works well when I use the IDE (Pycharm). However, when I use pyinstaller to pack it into an exec file. It gives me this error: "Fail to open XXXX.py".

Is there something wrong with packaging scipy.stats?

If I import headers like:

```
   import scipy.stats as sta
```

the i call sta.norm.xxxx

I have the same error

If I import headers like this:

```
  import scipy as sci
  import scipy.stats
```

The i call sci.stats.norm.XXXX

I can open the exec file but the function doesn't work.